# Socket.io Failed to load resource when used within Angular 5 and ElectronJS

Tags: angular, socket.io, electron

I have an angular 5 app, which works with websockets to constantly receive data from a server. The websockets are handled by Socket.IO, under an angular service called `Socketio.service`. Right now, I'm trying to turn it into an ElectronJS desktop app.

My problem is: when I run the angular app using `ng serve`, everything works fine, but when I run it as an ElectronJS app, I'm getting the error:

```
file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4aGo_y Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

polyfills.29c692a….bundle.js:1 GET http://file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4aGqYZ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I have double checked my code, and I don't see anything weird, and searching through Google, I can't find anyone with a similar problem.

Some of my existing code, for context:

`Socketio.service`:

```
// There are more Subjects, and more events to which the service listens,
// but they are all pretty much the same.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class SocketioService {
  namespace = '/test';
  socket: any;

  positionUpdate: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();


  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(location.protocol + '//' + 'localhost' + ':5000' +
    this.namespace, {
      'reconnection': true,
      'reconnectionDelay': 500,
      'reconnectionAttempts': 10
    });

    const self = this;

        this.socket.on('advisor_position', function(msg) {
      self.positionUpdate.next(msg);
    });
  }
}
```

`main.js` I'm using for ElectronJS:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

And, I have `socket.io-client` referenced in my packages.json:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    ...
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like the problem was coming from `location.protocol`. Apparently, electron's default protocol is not http (didn't try a console.log to see what is electron's protocol). The fix is: change `location.protocol` for `http:` (Using `ws:` also works).